# Handling of WebSocket Client Messages in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I have a case where my client opens a WebSocket connection upon which I subscribe to a MQTT topic and fetch the messages that I need to publish to this client. It could be that in-between the client disconnects and my message that I need to send to this client is not available anymore. So I re-write this message back to MQTT. Since I use Play Framework for my WebSocket server, I have an Actor that handles it. Here it is:

```
class OCPPActor(sink: ActorRef, chargingStationId: String, isPersistentConn: Boolean = false) extends Actor with Timers {

    // This will schedule to send the KeepAlive for WebSocket connections
    timers.startTimerWithFixedDelay("KeepAliveKey", "KeepAlive", 50.seconds)

    // Subscribe to dead letters to handle message sending failures
    context.system.eventStream.subscribe(self, classOf[DeadLetter])

    private val mqttConfig = bindings.appConfig.mqttConfig
    override def receive: Receive = {
      case jsValue: JsValue =>
        logger.info(s"Received OCPPCallRequest: \n ${Json.prettyPrint(jsValue)}")
        jsValue.validate[OCPPCallRequest].asEither match {
          case Right(ocppCall) => handleOCPPCallRequest(chargingStationId, ocppCall).onComplete {
            case Failure(fail) => sink ! JsError(s"${fail.getMessage}")
            case Success(succ) => sink ! Json.toJson(succ)
          }
          case Left(errors) =>
            logger.error(s"Errors occurred when validating OCPPCallRequest: \n $errors")
            sink ! Json.toJson(s"error -> ${errors.head._2}") // TODO: Work on this issue here on how we want to propagate errors
        }
      // For case where we pickup messages from the MQTT to be sent to the CS
      case csmsMessage: MqttCSMSMessage =>
        logger.info(s"Received CSMSMessage:\n${Json.prettyPrint(Json.toJson(csmsMessage))}")
        // Attempt to send CSMSMessage to the Charging Station
        sink ! csmsMessage
      case DeadLetter(msg, _, _) if msg.isInstanceOf[MqttCSMSMessage] =>
        logger.error("Failed to send CSMSMessage due to CS disconnection")
        val str = msg.asInstanceOf[MqttCSMSMessage].toString // TODO: This should be a Json String
        MqttClientFactory.publish(mqttConfig, chargingStationId, MqttQos.EXACTLY_ONCE, str)
      case "KeepAlive" =>
        logger.info("Received message KeepAlive .........")
        // TODO: How to deal with msgTypeId. I just choose a random value
        sink ! Json.toJson(heartbeatResponse(2,"HeartbeatRequest"))
      case msg: Any =>
        logger.warn(s"Received unknown message ${msg.getClass.getTypeName} that cannot be handled, " +
          s"eagerly closing websocket connection")
        timers.cancel("KeepAliveKey")
        self ! PoisonPill
    }
  }
```

As you can see that the case DeadLetter handles the scenarios where I know that the write to the client via the open WebSocket fails. Is this a good approach? What pitfalls could I expect?

Comment: I guess I was over thinking this problem. I could very well have a MQTT subscription created when my OCPPActor gets instantiated. It simplifies a lot.